# how to remove the 'home' link from top menu in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a website where i don't want the 'home' link in top menu, I just want to remove or disable it...I have tried this link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/60059/

but it didn't find any code in top.phtml (app > design > frontend > default (or whatever theme you have) > catalog > navigation > top.phtml ) like-

```
<li> yada /home statement </li>
```

or

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></a></li>
```

I have only

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Please give a solution.

I already tried using xml in customer.xml file but may be I didn't use it in proper xml file or proper code.

```
<reference name="top.links"> 
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
      <url helper="core/url/getHomeUrl" />
    </action>
 </reference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I figured it out.The Home link is there because of the menu plugin(custom responsive menu'). I disabled it from backend.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in the local.xml file of your active theme.

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/></action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: local.xml or page.xml? because on local.xml there is only database connection is defined.

Comment: Create a local.xml file if not exists in the app/design/frontend/default/<your theme>/layout/local.xml.
yes you said local.xml contains database connection.but this is their at the app/etc/local.xml
this is different local.xml i am reffering.

Answer (score 1):

As a hack you can hide it using css
find the class and add .class { display:none }